# Set Background ACtionbarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I used `getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable` to set Background for my actionbar Sherlock.

But when I used ActionMode (ActionMode.Callback) this does not work. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the ActionMode has it's own style and background. 
Not sure at the top of my head if you can set this programatically, but if there is im sure you can easily find it.

Otherwise look for and overwrite the following style;

```
    <style name="Widget.ActionMode">
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/actionModeBackground</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">?android:attr/actionModeSplitBackground</item>
    <item name="android:height">?android:attr/actionBarSize</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.ActionMode.Title</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle</item>
</style>
```